# How to concatenate two fields in Json - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using easy-autocomplete in a search form, and I would like to display both first name and last name in the suggestions list. I have the following in my search.json.jbuilder file :

```
json.users do
  json.array!(@users) do |user|
    json.name user.first_name
    json.url user_path(user)
  end
end
```

How can I modify it to add the last_name field please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add another entry or edit `json.name`

```
json.name "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
```

Comment: glad to be of help, would you accept the answer if it helped you